# simple camera intent on android tablet and smartphone

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, tablet, smartphone

Recently I start developing for my smartphone (motog) and I was able to run a small data capture program with a simple camera `OnActivityForResult` intent.

When I run it on the phone it run like a charm, everything was working how I was hoping.

The I try to install my program to a tablet device (Monster m7).  On the tablet the program run without a problem, then  I hit the camera button and the activity start, the program sends me to the camera view where I am able to capture the photo, but the program does not save the file where it's supposed to be (the same program works fine in the phone) the code of the intent is the next

```
    private void photo(String NE) {

        if (!NOMA.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            System.out.println("uno");
            Intent cameraa = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            System.out.println("dos");
            File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
            File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/SCR_ELECTRICO/Photos/"+NOMA.getText().toString());
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();  
            }
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy 'a' h:mm:ss a").format(new Date());
            File Photo = new File(dir,NOMA.getText().toString()+ NE+"_"+timeStamp+".jpg");
            imageuri= Uri.fromFile(Photo);
            cameraa.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imageuri);

            startActivityForResult(cameraa,1);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Asigna un nombre",
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult2(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent cameraa) {  
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, cameraa);
        if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageuri,null);
        }
    }
```

I've done some research on this but I haven't found anything to solve this problem.

Comment: Does it throw any exceptions?

Comment: Nothing created in "/SCR_ELECTRICO/Photos/"? How did you check it?

Comment: with the ES file explorer app, with the same app i was able to view the file in the smartphone

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is strange. I quit the timeStamp String, and now i can take the photo

```
String nombrefin=NOMA.getText().toString()+ NE+"_"+".jpg";
    File Photo = new File(dir,nombrefin);
```

some how the program doesnt accept the date command, and i need it.
well i have more research to do.